# Symfony2 wrong exception status

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm getting wrong exception status in my Symfony2 application. For testing purposes I've disabled `ElasticSearch` server and ofcourse Symfony application returns an error. In `dev` environment I'm getting `500 Internal Server Error` message and `500` status, which is OK. But in `prod` environment I'm getting `404 page not found` status (debuging with firebug), although application loads `error500.html.twig` view and not `error404.html.twig`, so somehow app knows that it is `500` error and loads correct view, but why status is `404`? How to change it?

Comment: did you check your webserver access log?

Comment: @DerStoffel I'll try to check it now. It is a remote server, so I'm not sure if I have all permissions to do that. Can you explain what to look in this log file?